# appending to list in a class

Tags: python, list, class, append

I want to know how to append to a list in a class...

```
class Dataset(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.grade=[]

    def add(self, x):
        return Dataset(self.grade.append(x))
```

This is an example of one of the things I have so far. In the test, I have...

```
def main():
    print('This is a program to compute the min, max, mean and')
    print('standard deviation for a set of numbers.\n')
    data = Dataset()
    while True:
        xStr = float(input('Enter a number (<Enter> to quit): '))
        if xStr == '':
            break
        data.add(xStr)
```

Do I have the right idea so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
class Dataset(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.grade=[]

    def add(self, x):
        self.grade.append(x)
```

As `list.append` is a mutating operation so there's no need to return anything.

Secondly as you're converting `xStr` to a float, so `if xStr == ''` is always going to be `False`. Better use try-except here because `float('')` will raise `ValueError`:

```
try:
   xStr = float(input('Enter a number (<Enter> to quit): '))
   data.add(xStr)
except ValueError:
   break
```

Another alternative to your `while-True` loop:

```
from functools import partial
par = partial(input, 'Enter a number (<Enter> to quit): ')
for inp in iter(par, ''):
    try:
       inp = float(inp)
       data.add(inp) 
    except ValueError:
       break
```

Lastly if you're on py3.x then there's no need to inherit from `object`, classic classes have been removed in py3.x.

**Demo:**

```
>>> data = Dataset()
>>> data.add(1)
>>> data.grade
[1]
```

Comment: +1 but `s = input(); if not s:` would be clearer than an unexceptional exception.

Comment: @msw I prefer EAFP. :)

Answer (score 2):

The add method should just be `def add(self, x): self.grade.append(x)`. Other then that, you're correct.